# Magento: Rewriting Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to override Magento order number creation by rewriting class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type.

app/code/local/Custom/MyModule/Model/Entity/Type.php:

```
<?php
class Custom_MyModule_Model_Entity_Type extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type {
    public function fetchNewIncrementId($storeId = null) {
        $incrementId = parent::fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);
        $incrementId = 'test' . $incrementId;
        return $incrementId;
    }
}
```

But what should I write to app/code/local/Custom/MyModule/etc/config.xml? See TODO1 and TODO2 below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_MyModule>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Custom_MyModule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <TODO1>
        <rewrite>
          <TODO2>Custom_MyModule_Model_Entity_Type</TODO2>
        </rewrite>
      </TODO1>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the core class

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_MyModule>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Custom_MyModule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <eav>
        <rewrite>
          <entity_type>Custom_MyModule_Model_Entity_Type</entity_type>
        </rewrite>
      </eav>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```